# Displaying multiple images via setInterval very slow in browsers

Tags: javascript, setinterval, coin-flipping

I'm trying to simulate a coin flip with javascript. It keeps changing images with 4 positions, creating an impression of flipping for 5 seconds and then sets the source to either the "head" image or "tails" image. I ran it in thimble mozilla and it works just perfect, so the code is fine but when running in browsers it can be very slow in changing the images. Is it because of the image sizes or there's something else? Each image is about 150kb in size.

```
 function flipCoin() {

     let coins = ["euro_head.png" , "euro_head_45.png" , 
                 "euro_head_90.png" , "euro_tail.png"];
      var image = document.getElementById("coin");
      var i = 0;
      var toss = setInterval(function(){
      if(coins.length == i){i = 0;}
      else {image.src = coins[i++];}
    },50);

    setTimeout(function( ) { 
      clearInterval(toss); 
      image.src = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "euro_head.png" :  "euro_tail.png"; 
     }, 5000);


  }
```

Comment: You should preload all the images first, and then run your flipCoin animation.

Comment: @FrankerZ is right. Also you could load preload the images using data URI and flip among those.

Comment: got it, thanks guys!

Comment: @TikoHarutyunyan Also, noticed a slight (Possible issue) with your `setInterval` function. There is one loop, where the image wont change (When it's resetting back to 0). If that's intended, you should leave as is, otherwise take out the else statement like I did below.

Answer (score 1):

Try preloading your images like below (Just having them in the coinImages array, should prevent them from being garbage collected):

```js
const coins = ["http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/00cc00?text=1", "http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/00b200?text=2",
  "http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/009900?text=3", "http://via.placeholder.com/50x50/007f00?text=4"
];
  
const coinImages = coins.map(src => {
  const img = new Image();
  img.src = src;
  return img;
});

function flipCoin() {
  const image = document.getElementById("coin");
  let i = 0;
  const toss = setInterval(function() {
    image.src = coins[i++ % coins.length];
  }, 50);

  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(toss);
    image.src = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=Heads" : "http://via.placeholder.com/50x50?text=Tails";
  }, 5000);


}

flipCoin();
```

```html
<img id="coin" />
```

Here, you can see the performance below:

**With preload:**
[image]

**Without preload:**
[image]